# ListTile susbtitle renderflex overflowed

Tags: flutter

I have ListTile subtitle which like this:

```
     subtitle:Flexible(flex:1,child:Row(children: [
                    (widget.condiments!=null)?Padding(
                 child:Text(condimentList,style: TextStyle(color:Colors.grey)),
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10)):null,
               ])),
 trailing:  Row(             
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,     
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete))])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 244 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Row
```

I was hoping that wrapping it around Flexible should do it but seems like I don't quite know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your text in Expanded that's it, no need to use wrap for row.

Check this at [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ccfe8c299a73d6303279315a7ec2d327&null_safety=true) for UI output.

```
ListTile(
      title: const Text('Test'),
      trailing: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))
      ]),
      subtitle: Row(children: const [
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Text(
            'This is a test & this will have a very long paragragh to check the errors once. This is a test & this will have a very long paragragh to check the errors once.',
          ),
        ))
      ]),
    );
```

UI Output with expanded:

[image: UI Output with expanded:]

UI Output without expanded:

[image: UI Output without expanded:]

Comment: Please see my edited question. It seems like the issue is with the trailing code.

Comment: @bangbang I updated my answer, I didnt face any issues, Please check the dart pad in the answer, for UI output

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
  width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child:  Row(children: [
                (widget.condiments!=null)?Padding(
             child:Text(condimentList,style: TextStyle(color:Colors.grey)),
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10)),
           ]),
):null;
```

Comment: Try wrapping row widget with Sizedbox having screen width as it's width.

Comment: I am getting this error: 
The getter 'width' isn't defined for the type 'MediaQueryData'.
Try importing the library that defines 'width', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'width'

Comment: A RenderFlex overflowed by 199 pixels on the right. From 204 to 199

Comment: Please see my edited code in the question. I added the trailing code and I am certain this is what's causing the error.